# Scan uploaded files for viruses

Tags: security, fileupload, file-storage

I have a public Salesforce Community that I use like Web To Case - for clients to create new cases in my org.

For implementing that, I have developed a lightning web component that creates a case.

After creating the case, the page goes into a second stage that the client can upload files, this is implemented also with a lighting web component with: `lightning-file-upload`.

**PROBLEM**

Because this is a public community, anyone can upload any files into our cases, and someone can upload a virus that eventually our support analyst might open and affect his computer and the whole company.

Salesforce does not scan for viruses any on the files uploaded (ContentVersion, Attachments, Documents...), and I see on the web 2 apps that offer virus scanning for Salesforce:

1. [EZProtect](https://adaptus.com/portfolio/ezprotect-cybersecurity-file-management/) - does not offer in AppExchange
2. [F-Secure](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFntJUAT)

**QUESTIONS**

1. What is the best approach to deal with this threat?
2. Can you please give me examples how you have addressed this problem?
3. Anyone that used one of these apps - can you please provide some feedback and pros and cons?

Comment: EzProtect now has AppExchange (https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMkfrUAD&tab=e)
Was thinking a maybe a File Trigger to call some antivirus api to scan before uploading to SF?